# How to query two values from index? Appsync Query Dynamodb

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

My resolver template

```
{
   "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        "expression" : "receiverusername = :receiverusername and createdat > :createdat",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":receiverusername" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.identity.username),
            ":createdat" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.lastDate),
        }
    },
    "index" : "receiverusername-createdat-index",
}
```

I am trying to query the date and username but I keep on getting this error

```
{
  "data": {
    "listMyMessages": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "listMyMessages"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:DynamoDbException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 7I18ODEK46H52NMBSF99OTNSQ7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
    }
  ]
```

How do I query this ?

I tried to learn from documentations but nothing gives me any clue!

Answer (score 0):

Querying 2 values at the same time is not possible for DynamoDB, since every GSI creates a duplicate table with different index. A good solution I can think of is querying indexes in parallel and returning their intersaction.

Comment: But when you go to Dynamodb UI you can query using two values of index, the partition key and sort key. Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: Yeah So I got it. It is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and it worked.
And yes I am not touching or investigating why.

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index" : "receiverusername-createdat-index",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "receiverusername = :receiverusername and createdat > :createdat",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":receiverusername" : {
                "S" : "${context.identity.username}"
            },
            ":createdat": {
                "S": "${ctx.args.lastDate}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did not use sort key but just index keys

[image]

Comment: The reason for that is that, the "createdat" variable you are using is a range key, not an index key.

Comment: @CanArdaAydin I did not, just used index keys.

Comment: Well thats on me then, sorry for the confusion. Though, I am happy that I learned ^^